# chart.js pie chart built in interactions

Tags: chart.js

When using echarts, in several lines of code the following can be achieved: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=pie-doughnut , more specifically notice the entrance animation and the hover behaviors and the legends hover and the smooth tooltip movement and legend click behavior and the quick chart rerendering.

On the other hand echarts lacks touch events support and some other stuff and thus I wanted to use chart.js to build this same doughnut chart to see if chart.js is capable of it. The chart.js examples I saw online have very basic animations and interactions.

I saw in chart.js website that support is given by creating appropriate stackoverflow question with chart.js tag, so I am creating this question to ask if its possible to create a dougnut chart with the described behaviors using chart.js

Comment: You can achieve a [similar visual result](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html), yes. You'll need to do the hard work yourself of reading the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/), checking the [examples](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/), and figuring out if what you want to achieve is possible. If you have a specific problem with your code that you need help with then you can ask here on SO by including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me.